# What are some good resources to learn about perturbative and non-perturbative approaches to QCD, for example Lattice QCD, at an introductory level?

Tags: resource-recommendations, perturbation-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-model, non-perturbative

I am writing at an introductory level about the anomalous magnetic moment of the muon and part of that is the subsequent Lattice QCD that potentially verifies the results from the experiments that have been conducted. An important part as I understand is that the strong nuclear force is non-perturbative, as is Lattice QCD, so perturbative approaches won't yield sufficient results when doing these types of calculations. I want to get a basic understanding of perturbative/non-perturbative approaches to these issues and their importance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can recommend the book by Gattringer and Lang "Quantum Chromodynamics on the Lattice - an Introductory Presentation". I read it in an introductory course to LQCD and found it really easy to read, although it covers only the very basics as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

A more basic approach than Gattringer and Lang is given in

Francesco Knechtli, Michael Günther, Michael Peardon, Lattice Quantum Chromodynamics Practical Essentials, Springer, 2017

It aims to graduate students who are approaching this topic.